# SugarCRM REST API: get_relationships returns empty beans

Tags: java, rest, sugarcrm

I try to load contacts from a given account using the REST api of sugarcrm using Java. This "kind of" works... My test scenario should return two records. It does, but the records do a) not contain all fields and b) all the returned fields have empty values:

See the entry_list part of the returned JSON:

```
{"entry_list": [
{
    "id": null,
    "module_name": "Contacts",
    "name_value_list": {
        "name": {
            "name": "name",
            "value": ""
        },
        "deleted": {
            "name": "deleted",
            "value": 0
        },
        "do_not_call": {
            "name": "do_not_call",
            "value": "0"
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": null,
    "module_name": "Contacts",
    "name_value_list": {
        "name": {
            "name": "name",
            "value": ""
        },
        "deleted": {
            "name": "deleted",
            "value": 0
        },
        "do_not_call": {
            "name": "do_not_call",
            "value": "0"
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I set as rest_data in my request:

```
    rest_data.put("session", sessionId);
    rest_data.put("module_name", moduleName);
    rest_data.put("module_id", sourceId);
    rest_data.put("link_field_name", relationField);
    rest_data.put("related_module_query", "");
    rest_data.put("related_fields", Arrays.asList());
    rest_data.put("related_module_link_name_to_fields_array", Arrays.asList());
    rest_data.put("offset", 0);
    rest_data.put("order_by", "name ASC");
    rest_data.put("limit", 0);
```

So I'd expect that I receive:
- all records -> works
- all fields for every record -> works not
- all values for all fields for every record -> works not

I'm using v4_1 of the REST api.

Does anybody have some hints on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike `get_entry_list` works you cannot specify an empty array for the `related_fields` parameter. You must specify at least one field name.

Comment: I expected to get all fields if I specify an empty list as at other places. Found it out myself, sorry for not updating this.